# Get all upload id from Dropzone Js in a set of array or JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dropzone.js

I have a form of Job Application for people to apply. The form also allows people to upload their cv and cover letters.

I use Dropzone to upload multiple files (CV and Cover letters). And I want to get a set of ids that has been uploaded in to array or json. So that I can use it to create relationship with an job application form

```
var idResult = "";
    Dropzone.options.uploadDemo = {
        maxFilesize: 5, //accept file size 5MB
        paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        acceptedFiles: ".pdf,.doc,.docx,.docm,.docb,.dotx,.dotm", //acccept file extension
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        init: function () {
            this.on("success", function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.xhr.response);
                $('#@Html.IdFor(x=>x.Applicant.UploadIds)').val(data.UploadIds);
            });
```

here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("Career/SaveUploadedFile")]
    public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile()
    {
        try
        {
            string uploadId = string.Empty;
            foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                //Save file content goes here

                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)

                {

                    var originalDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format("{0}Upload\\Document", Server.MapPath(@"\")));

                    string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "file");

                    var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                    bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString);

                    if (!isExists)
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

                    var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString, file.FileName);

                    file.SaveAs(path);


                    var upload = TTCHRFacade.CreateUpload(new Upload()
                    {
                        FileName = file.FileName,
                        FileSize = file.ContentLength,
                        FileExtention = file.ContentType,
                        GUIDFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        UploadDate = DateTime.Now
                    });
                    uploadId += upload.UploadId.ToString() + ",";
                    //return PartialView("ApplicantUploadTemplate", upload);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Set as bad request (400)
                    Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                    ModelState.AddModelError("error", "Need Files.");
                    return Json(ModelState.Values.FirstOrDefault().Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return Json(new { uploadId }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //TODO

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Set as bad request (400)
            Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json(ModelState.Values.FirstOrDefault().Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

Note: The application form and upload form are in the same view

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `data.uploadId` in the data passed to your ajax method's success call should give you the new id.

Comment: yeah. But it's not a set of array of id.

Comment: You can return an array of ids. See the answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a single id, you should return a collection of Id's

```
var uploadIds = new List<string>();
foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
{
   // Your existing code goes here
   var uploadId = upload.UploadId.ToString();
   uploadIds.Add(uploadId);
}
//Now return the list of Ids
return Json(uploadIds, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This will return an array of Ids

Comment: It looks like it's working. However, I am not able to return the result in view page. :3

Comment: where do you want to return the result in the view page ? what result ?